# Solr/Lucene simple operator "or" missunderstanding / Seach same word in differnt fields

Tags: solr, lucene

Learning Solr/Lucene Syntax, using Solr Admin in Browser.
There I try to search for the same word in two differnt fields with following syntax:

`content:myword` -> results found

`content:myword OR title:existingTitle` -> results found

but

`content:myword OR title:myword -> ZERO results found`, why? It is "or".

also tried without operator which should be equal to "or" , also tried "|" and "||"

this happens when I try to find the same word in one of multipe fields

[edit]

Here are the solr url requests:

content:fahrzeug title:fahrzeug
http://xxx/solr/core_de/select?q=content%3Afahrzeug%20title%3Afahrzeug

content:fahrzeug OR title:fahrzeug
http://xxx/solr/core_de/select?q=content%3Afahrzeug%20OR%20title%3Afahrzeug

content:fahrzeug | title:fahrzeug
http://xxx/solr/core_de/select?q=content%3Afahrzeug%20%7C%20title%3Afahrzeug

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":5,
    "params":{
      "q":"content:fahrzeug OR title:fahrzeug",
      "debugQuery":"1"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"invalid boolean value: 1",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: It may be caused by a wrong url encoding, can you show us the actual Solr request for each example ?

Comment: You can also append `debugQuery=true` to your request to see what the server actually parsed your query as. Depending on the query parser, it might not be parsed as you expect it to, so include the whole Solr query string.

Comment: thanks for your answers! i will put the request urls in the question above. So my syntax for the "or" is correct?

Comment: If you append debugQuery you can check if there's a query parser being set through the core settings as well - the old dismax parser might not do what you expect it to do in this case. `field:foo OR field2:foo` should work as you expect it to, yes.

Comment: there is indeed a solr exeption the debug output. -> see above. is there a basic failure with the installation. it is a default installation of vers. 7.7.1

Comment: I dont get exception on same query: http://www119.pxia.de:8983/solr/core_de/select?debugQuery=on&fl=*%2C%20score&q=content%3Afahrzeug%20OR%20title%3Afahrzeug

Comment: The error that you are getting (invalid boolean value: 1) is because you are passing `1` as value for `debugQuery`. You should pass true instead: `debugQuery=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, that it is configured like this:

Try: 
`http://www119.pxia.de:8983/solr/core_de/select?fq=content%3Afahrzeug%20title%3Afahrzeug&q=*%3A*` - this returns correct documents. So those documents are there if only filtering is used. Query use more complex conditions, your default configuration is:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="qf">content^40.0 title^5.0 keywords^2.0 tagsH1^5.0 tagsH2H3^3.0 tagsH4H5H6^2.0 tagsInline^1.0</str>
        <str name="pf">content^2.0</str>
        <str name="df">content</str>
        <int name="ps">15</int>

        <str name="mm">2&lt;-35%</str>
        <str name="mm.autoRelax">true</str>
...
```

Parser and boosting may play a key role here.
I am not familiar with edixmax parser, please check: [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html)
I would guess `mm` parameter may be causing this.
Anyway its strange, that OR does not work as we are use to from boolean algebra.

```
"debug":{
"queryBoosting":{
  "q":"title:Home OR content:Perfekt",
  "match":null},
"rawquerystring":"title:Home OR content:Perfekt",
"querystring":"title:Home OR content:Perfekt",
"parsedquery":"+(title:hom content:perfekt)~2 ()",
"parsedquery_toString":"+((title:hom content:perfekt)~2) ()",
"explain":{
  "bf72a75534ba703e4b8dc7194f92ce34223fc0d2/pages/1/0/0/0":"\n4.8893824 = sum of:\n  4.8893824 = sum of:\n    1.9924302 = weight(title:hom in 0) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n      1.9924302 = score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n        1.9924302 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n          1.0 = docFreq\n          10.0 = docCount\n        1.0 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1) from:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)\n    2.8969522 = weight(content:perfekt in 0) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n      2.8969522 = score(doc=0,freq=5.0 = termFreq=5.0\n), product of:\n        1.4816046 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n          2.0 = docFreq\n          10.0 = docCount\n        1.9552802 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n          5.0 = termFreq=5.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.75 = parameter b\n          508.3 = avgFieldLength\n          184.0 = fieldLength\n"},
"QParser":"ExtendedDismaxQParser",
```

Check `"parsedquery":"+(title:hom content:perfekt)~2 ()"` it basically says, that both title and content must be there:
 [Solr operators](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/the-standard-query-parser.html#boolean-operators-supported-by-the-standard-query-parser)

Comment: Sometimes the sollution is so easy, thanks a lot.
Using fq and q in this way helps to get it work, thanks a lot!